# Fourier transform of sigmoid function times damped sinusoid

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Consider the sigmoid function
$$
h_k(t) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-kt}}
$$
as an approximation to the Heaviside step function $u(t)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Given
$$
f(t) = h_k(t) \times s(t) \equiv \frac{1}{1+e^{-kt}} \times (A \cos(\omega_0 t) + B \sin(\omega_0 t)) \exp(-\alpha t),
$$
where $\alpha > 0$ and I used $\times$ for clarity, I want to evaluate its Fourier transform (FT)
$$
F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \exp(-i\omega t) dt.
$$
This integral exists if $\alpha < k$, so we choose $k$ accordingly.

After failing to evaluate the integral directly, my approach was to calculate $F(\omega)$ as
$$
F(\omega) = (H_k * S)(\omega),
$$
where $*$ denotes convolution and $H_k(\omega)$ and $S(\omega)$ are the FTs of $h_k(t)$ and $s(t)$.

As this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812966/566289) shows,
$$
H_k(\omega) = \pi \delta(\omega) - \frac{i\pi}{k \sinh(\pi\omega/k)}
$$
in the "distributional sense" (which I understand to be in the sense of Lighthill's generalized functions), which for $k \rightarrow \infty$ indeed reduces nicely to the FT of $u(t)$, i.e. $U(\omega)$:
$$
H_\infty(\omega) = \pi\delta(\omega) + \frac{1}{i\omega} = U(\omega).
$$
The problem with my approach is that I cannot calculate $S(\omega)$, as its FT does not converge ($s(t)$ does not vanish for $t \rightarrow 
-\infty$), but perhaps it might still be possible "in the distributional sense".

**My questions:** Can $F(\omega)$ be evaluated in a nice closed form? If not, how does $|F(\omega)|$ fall off for $\omega \rightarrow \infty$? This should be <s>slower</s> faster [edit] than $1/\omega$ for $k < \infty$, am I correct?

Comment: I think that $\exp(-\alpha t)$ grows too fast for negative $t$ to have a Fourier transform in the space of tempered distributions. And so does $s(t)$

Comment: For $0 < \alpha < k$, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac {e^{-\alpha t}} {1 + e^{-k t}} e^{-i \omega t} dt =
\frac \pi {i k} \operatorname{csch} \frac {\pi (\omega - i \alpha)} k.$$
Multiplication by $e^{\pm i \omega_0 t}$ corresponds to shifts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't miss something, for $0 < \alpha < k$ the function $f$ belongs to [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). This space is closed under Fourier transforms. Therefore $F=\mathcal{F}f$ is also in Schwartz space, meaning that it is $C^\infty$ and that all of its derivatives fall off faster than $|x|^{-n}$ for every $n \geq 0$ as $|x| \to \infty.$

Comment: Indeed, I mistakenly wrote "slower" while meaning "faster"; I edited the post accordingly. Thanks for the providing the theoretical background. FYI, I just discovered that Wolfram Alpha spits out [the improper integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2F(1%2Be%5E(-k*t))*e%5E(i*W*t)*e%5E(-a*t)*e%5E(-i*w*t))) associated with $F(\omega)$, but for which the limit $t\rightarrow \pm \infty$ doesn't seem to make sense, and which only seems valid for the case $\omega=\omega_0$... Would you mind taking a quick look?

Comment: I know too little about hypergeometric functions to be able to say much about the result. But I guess that the factor $e^{(k-\alpha)t}$ will be small when ${}_2F_1(\ldots)$ is big and vice versa in a way that makes the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ be finite.

Comment: OK, after some work I see that that is indeed what happens. Was also my first serious encounter with this function. Thanks!